# PowerShell -- Looking for equivalent of Perl's redo

Tags: powershell, for-loop

I have the following PowerShell loop:

```
Set-Variable -Name YELLOW -Option ReadOnly -Value 0
Set-Variable -Name ORANGE -Option ReadOnly -Value 1
Set-Variable -Name RED    -Option ReadOnly -Value 2

While ($true) {
    for ($color = $YELLOW; $color -le $RED; $color++) { 
        $LastWriteTime = ((Get-Item $FilePath).LastWriteTime)
        $waitTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-($WarningTimeArray[$color]))
        $SleepTime = ($LastWriteTime - $waitTime).TotalSeconds
        If ($SleepTime -gt 0) {
            $WarningFlagArray[$color] = $false;
            SendMail ("Start-Sleep -Seconds" + $SleepTime)
            Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepTime
            Continue  #Actually want a "redo"
        }
        ElseIf (-not $WarningFlagArray[$color]) {   
            SendMail $WarningMessageArray[$color]
           $WarningFlagArray[$color] = $true
        }
    }
}
```

When PowerShell hits the "Continue", it continues back to the top of the `for` loop, and goes to the next color.

In Perl, you have `last` (equivalent to PowerShell's `break`) and you have `next` (equivalent to PowerShell's `continue`). You also have the `redo` which goes back to the top of the loop, but doesn't increment the `for` loop counter.

Is there an equivalent Powershell command to Perl's `redo` function for the `for` loop?

I can easily convert the statement into a `while` loop to get around this particular issue, but I was wondering if there is something like `redo` anyway.

Comment: AFAIK, most languages don't have a `redo` equivalent.

Comment: @kirilloid I know, but it's nice in cases like this. Changed it to a `while` loop. First time I ever used PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure PowerShell doesn't support what you're looking for.  You can have labelled break and continue statements but neither will take you to the top of the *inside* of the associated loop/switch construct.  If PowerShell had a goto statment you'd be set but I'm glad it doesn't have that keyword.  :-)  For more info on labelled break/continue see the about_break help topic.

Comment: I changed the loop to a `while` loop, and put the increment in the `Else` clause. That did what I want (retest after the sleep). I normally do scripting in Python or Perl. However, this is a PC shop and I can't install either of these on this system. It has PowerShell, so that was my choice. Never used it before.

Comment: Given your background, I think you'll like it especially considering the alternative: batch files.  :-)

Comment: @AndyArismendi Batch files or VBScript - hmm, which is the lesser of two evils. :-)  If I were mostly launching exe's I'd use batch but if I had a lot of control flow I'd use VBScript I guess.  I'm really glad PowerShell handles both scenarios superbly.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent of Perl's **redo** would be nice, and I hope they introduce it in a future version, but mainly because it would be useful in **Foreach-Object**, **foreach**, and **while** loops.

However, in a **for** loop, at least a typical one, you can easily reproduce the functionality by simply reversing  the incrementation immediately before the **continue** statement.

In this case, since the increment statement (aka `<repeat>` in the PowerShell documentation) is `$color++`, just stick `$color--` immediately before `continue`. For clarity/elegance, I'd suggest putting them on one line to make it clearer that it's essentially a single loop control contsruct:

```
$color--; continue
```

The only reasons I can think of why that would ever not work:

- You're otherwise manipulating the loop variable inside the loop. But I think that's terrible programming style and anyone who's doing that deserves to have their script break. ;)
- You have a condition that depends on some other variable that can change within the loop, e.g. `for ($i = 0; $i -lt $j; $i++)` where `$j` can change within the loop.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't like.  You shouldn't change the value of the incremator of the `for` loop. That can leave to sloppy programming. Developers expect the inviolability of the `for` incrementor.  The `redo` gets around this because it doesn't *modify* the value at all. It just prevents it from changing when the loop is reexecuted. The `break/continue/last/next/redo` statements aren't the dreaded `goto` because they all return to the same place. They're shortcuts that help clarify the logic.